# Theme Color Changing in iOS

Tags: ios, colors, themes

I have seen this question asked before however I haven't found a response that seems to work too well.

I am new to Xcode and am trying to make an app for iOS where a user can go into the settings tab and choose a theme such as Red where the buttons, background etc. can change to a certain color. Is there a way to do this by referencing the attributes tab and then telling Xcode to change the button property if the settings button is pressed.

Also if the background is using an image is there a way to change that image with another one if a button is pressed.

I am using Xcode 8.2 and using Swift 3.

Comment: Is this  _settings tab_ in your app or are you referring to Settings app?

Comment: The settings tab is in the app.

Comment: Xcode has nothing to do with this.

Comment: @rmaddy what do you mean?